# Can't log in to StackExchange chat (Firefox 4.0b8)

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

I can't seem to log in to StackExchange Chat; I've tried:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global
- 404 Not Found - https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/login/global/request
- Logging Out Everywhere
- Success
- Destroying Credentials
- Success
- Logging In
- Success
- Problems logging in?
- Test 1: JavaScript – ok
- Test 2: Cookies – ok
- Test 3: Messaging – ok
- Test 4: Storage – ok
- Test 5: Communication with StackAuth – failed
- IFRAMEs – ok
- JavaScript – ok
- Storage – ok
- https://superuser.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login
- Log in to chat.stackexchange.com
- 404 Not Found - https://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global-fallback

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't support beta browsers. If the problem can be replicated in a released version then it will be looked at.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, it was because I had disabled sending the `Referer` header in Firefox. Not sure why the 404 error code was chosen for "missing Referer header", though...

Comment: I'm investigating...

Answer (score 2):

The `referer` is required due to some shared internal processing to validate everything is happy between the sites. I have clarified the message the user sees for this scenario.

Comment: I'm behind a nazi-proxy that strips that header out. Is there a workaround that enables me to use chat? For example, a URL param I can use to specify the stack I'm coming from?

Comment: @Ranieri you can just go to the "site" tab? for example http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=bicycles.stackexchange.com

Comment: If I follow your link, I can see the char rooms associated with "bicycles". However, I'm not logged in ("Log In" in header). If i click on a chatroom, I access the chat but I can't participate because I am not logged in. If instead I click "log in" in the header I end up on the chat login page. "Log in with stackexchange" gives me the error "No referer was present - this may be due to a browser setting" (which is due to the naziproxy). Test and help page gives me the all-clear.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers in beta are not supported by Stack Exchange policy.

You can view a [list of supported browsers here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/89334).